# How to use unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How much values will you give to me?");
        int count = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] list = new double[count];
        int x = 0;
        do
        {
            list[x] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            x++;
        } while (x < count);
    }
}
```

In this code, I have to ask the user for 'how much values they will give to me?'. But I want that, user don't have to specify the value to the program. It should happen automatically. I mean user will start giving numbers as soon as they start program. The program will start calculating when user type 'start' instead of a value.

I don't know if I have successfully explain my problem.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to stackoverflow. So, I don't know anything about it. Just created acc here.

Comment: Ask for integer in the loop, and exit from loop when user type "calculate", for example. Or ask to type integers separated by comma, then split them in the arrays of integers.

Comment: Even for a new member, it's more intuitive to use text to express code not image!

Comment: If you are new, you were suggested to read [ask] before posting a question. Please do so, and [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: As an Idea, Create a `List<>` and then `.add()` to the list in a loop as long as the user is giving integer values, `if (input == "start")` do the math.

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. And i'm going to edit my post.

Comment: well, post edited.

Comment: Both List and Array have an Average() method.

Comment: First find out what happens when the user types "asdf" instead of a number.  Fix that.  You can then get to the next step, the user can now type "done" when they are done entering numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how you could do this is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool read = true;
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        do{
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int x = 0; 
            if(input == "start")
            {
                read = false;
            }
            else if(int.TryParse(input, out x))
            {
                list.Add(x);
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            }
        } while(read);
        foreach(var z in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z);   
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to adjust this to your needs, but this is how you could handle it.

Notice the `List<>` it is dynamically growing and shrinking. That way you don't have to specify the amount of numbers you want to add. That way you can just add as long as you wish till you give the `Start` command.

Comment: [Online compiler example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lIrziZ)

Comment: Okay downvoted without any reason? Good, that helps improving answers.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. And, yeah I did not down voted you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Average
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator calc = new Calculator();
            bool read = true;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            do
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                int x = 0;
                if (input == "start")
                {
                    read = false;
                }
                else if (int.TryParse(input, out x))
                {
                    list.Add(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                }
            } while (read);
            Console.WriteLine(calc.Average(list));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Calculator
    {
        public double Average(List<int> list)
        {
            double value = 0;
            foreach(var z in list)
            {
                value = value + z;
            }
            return value / (list.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, vulpex. For helping me.